# Creating AAD user in API Management using ARM also creates Basic

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

When adding/updating AAD user with ARM template/resources.explorer, why does a Basic user also get created?
This is the payload:

```
{  
"apiVersion": "2017-03-01",  
"type": "users",  
"name": "user1",  
"properties": {  
    "firstName": "FirstName",  
    "lastName": "LastName",  
    "email": "[parameters('user1Email')]",  
    "state": "active",  
    "identities": [  
        {  
        "provider": "Aad",  
        "id": "[parameters('user1UserId')]"  
        }  
    ]  
}  
}
```

As you can see i do not include the

```
{  
"provider": "Basic",  
"id": "basic.userg@basic.com"
}
```

I don't want to create Basic Auth, I only want Azure AD. 
When creating AD user from the developer portal we don't get this behaviour, but with ARM it also creates Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see at the moment is to do a second PATCH (!) request with same payload but no Basic identity.